# LPBoost and TotalBoost not working?

Tags: matlab

Been trying to reproduce [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ensemble-methods.html#btg0jov) which requires both Statistics and Optimization toolboxes; which I have. (v7.5 and v6.0 respectively; Matlab R2011a)

However, I keep on getting the error

*??? Error using ==> fitensemble at 270

You cannot fit an ensemble for TotalBoost because it is not an ensemble method.*

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a step I am missing to incorporate TotalBoost into the allowed methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same error on Matlab2012a, but the example you mentioned is from the 2012b documentation. If you look on the tool box's [release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/release-notes.html), you'll see that:

"... **R2012b New Features, Bug Fixes, Compatibility Considerations**

- Boosting algorithms for imbalanced data, sparse ensembles, and multiclass boosting, with self termination... "

Comment: That explains it! Should have thought to look at the release notes. Perfect answer.